# Code with const keyword won't compile

Tags: c++

I don't understand  why this piece of code won't compile.

I get following error in line `return source->GetA();`

> cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const class FooStruct' to 'class
>   FooStruct &'

If I remove the `const` keyword it compiles fine.

```
class FooStruct
{
  int a;
public:
  int GetA() {return a;};

  int Bar(const FooStruct *source);
};


int FooStruct::Bar(const FooStruct *source)
{
  return source->GetA();
}
```

The code itself doesn't make sense. It has been stripped down from some real code and its only purpose is to illustrate the problem.

Comment: You need to make your function constant too

Comment: You declared that the object pointed by source will not be modified by the function Bar. Then you call function GetA() on source that may modify the pointed object unless it's declared as const.

Comment: Imagine if you'd written `int GetA() {a++; return 5;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of this line:

```
return source->GetA();
```

Here you are trying to execute `GetA` function on the pointer that you got. If the pointed object is `const`, the function must also be `const`, because:

- Both `const` and non-const functions can be executed on non-const objects
- Only `const` functions can be executed on const objects.

It is a good idea to mark all the functions that do not modify the state of the object as `const`, so they can be used on const objects (e.g. in functions that accept `const T &` as a parameter).

So in your case, the class should look like:

```
class FooStruct
{
public:
  int GetA() const {return a;}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `GetA` itself needs to be marked `const`:

```
int GetA() const {
    return a;
}
```

This then allows a `const source*` pointer to call that function.